# Machatziz hashekel

Tags: money, shiurim-measurements

How much money is a Machatziz hashekel.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5685

Comment: The comments to this question are related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16261/chad-gadya-the-price-of-a-kid-goat?lq=1 -- 1/2 Shekel is 2 zuz

Comment: Also related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27516

Comment: What is a "Machatziz hashekel"?

Answer (score 5):

The Shekel in the Torah was a measure of weight of silver.

Rashi (Exodus 21:32) says the Shekel is "half an ounkia as used in Kolonia"; to translate from Old French, half an ounce as was used in the German city of Cologne.  The shekel is generally understood to be about half a [troy ounce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troy_ounce); the Chazon Ish is quoted as saying the shekel is 0.51 troy ounces.  (See [this article for many more details](http://onthemainline.blogspot.com/2010/02/early-printed-images-of-ancient-shekels.html)).  So a half shekel is about a 1/4 of a troy ounce.   (That's about the same weight as the [new American gold-colored dollar coins](http://www.usmint.gov/about_the_mint/?action=coin_specifications).)

Today, silver is worth about $18.70 per troy ounce; taking $18.70 / 4, it looks like right now, a half-shekel's weight of silver is worth about **$4.70**.

Answer (score 5):

According to the Rambam (Hil. Shekalim 1:2), a shekel was originally the weight of 320 barleycorns of silver, and this was later increased to 384. So half a shekel would be, respectively, 160 or 192 barleycorns. According to measurements given [here](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%AA_%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA,_%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94) a barleycorn is around 1/20 of a gram, so half a shekel would be 8 or 9.6 grams. This comes to about 0.25-0.3 troy ounce.

(For purposes of pidyon haben, where five silver shekalim are required, there are customs to use as much as 117 grams of silver. This would make half a shekel, 1/10 of that amount, 11.7 grams or 0.38 troy ounce.)

Comment: Alex, I think we answered this one simultaneously -- and as you can see, though with different sources, basically the same answer.

Comment: Sort of, although it was my understanding that Rashi and Rambam actually disagree about the weight of a shekel. (Ramban used the proof from the shekel coin that he saw in Israel - discussed in the post at On the Main Line that you linked - in favor of Rashi's value.)

Comment: Yes.  But the figures are all in the same ballpark.

Comment: @Shalom, although I can read barleycorn much more fluently than ounkia ;)