# Cash value of 'perutah'

Tags: money, halacha, shiurim-measurements

How much is a 'perutah' worth in modern currency?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1357

Comment: Also related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27516

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe for most Halachic topics today that require "one *prutah's* worth" of cash, goods, or services (e.g. the minimum needed to effect a wedding), we go with an economic definition: the smallest amount of money that can buy something. Despite inflation, there are [plenty of things you can still buy](https://www.oldtimecandy.com/collections/candy-by-type-bubble-chewing-gum?sort=price-ascending) today for fifty cents or less, so fifty cents is certainly *shaveh prutah*; I'm not sure whether it's a nickel, dime, or quarter, but fifty cents certainly is enough. Or as someone once said to my father:

> You mean instead of a gold ring, a guy could march down the aisle and give the bride the little metal tab off his soda can?

My father replied:

> No, that's not nearly enough. He'd have to give her the *entire can* of soda.

Comment: Party City (at least my local branch) sells Hershey's Kisses in the checkout lanes at fifteen for a dollar. That's the cheapest regular price (maning that that's always the price, and the thing is always for sale) that I know of (except for that of things sold by weight, which I suppose can be cheaper if small enough: nuts, perhaps).

Comment: msh210, all you have proven is that a dollar can buy 15 Hershey Kisses. If you cannot buy one Kiss for 6.7 cents on its own then you cannot tell me that 6.7 cents is a shaveh perutah.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified: They're sold by the piece, so seven cents (plus tax) gets you one.

Comment: I stand corrected!

Comment: I can testify that I once bought 100 sheets of loose leaf notebook paper at an Office Max for 1 penny, and I paid in cash!

Comment: What is source of "the smallest amount of money that can buy something"

Comment: And if you can buy a barley coin of silver for it...

Answer (score 11):

The weight of a *p'ruta* was half that of a barleycorn, and it was silver. Assuming — without justification — that barleycorns weigh now what they did then, and other unjustified assumptions, we have: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grain_%28unit%29#History) gives the weight of a barleycorn as about 65 mg. At about 31,103.4768 mg per troy ounce and a current price of silver of about USD28.20, that gives about 2.9 cents to a *p'ruta*.

Comment: R'Shalom's answer, below, deals with "[h]alachic topics today that require 'one prutah's worth'", and I don't claim that mine does. That is, my answer is not an halachic answer but a monetary one: I'm not answering how much a _shave p'ruta_ is in _halacha_ but how much a p'ruta is actually.

Comment: [Will](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1095) [mentions elsewhere](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12335) that a Rabbi Mordechai Willig, a _posek_, says that a _p'ruta_ is "the monetary equivalent of 1,000th of an ounce of silver". This accords approximately with what I write in this answer.

Comment: Thanks for cross-referencing me.  At today's rates, a US nickel still suffices as a prutah - but when visiting Israel, 10 agorot no longer cuts it.  Better reach for two 10ag coins, or better yet, a big half-shekel, when asked by assorted beggars in the Holy Land.

Comment: R' Chaim Naeh [evaluates](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20888&st=&pgnum=354) a perutah as 1/40th of a gram of silver (25mg), which would make it's USD value 2 cents at the [time of posting](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.025+grams+silver+in+usd)

Comment: @Michoel, that's *about* the same as Rabbi Willig and as what I wrote in this answer. Thanks for the info. Might I suggest you post it as a separate answer here?

Comment: @Michoel hazon ish also says also that a barely grain is 1/20 of a gram, it happens to fit with the waight of a "jeweller's grain or pearl grain" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grain_(unit) also to  1⁄4 of a carat (.2gram) ("1 carat = 4 grains" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carat_(mass)#Greco-Roman )

Comment: 16.30here  http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14332&pgnum=93 and  66.21 here http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14331&pgnum=177

Comment: A prutah was almost certainly [not silver](https://www.google.co.il/books/edition/The_Coins_of_Herod/gQEyAQAAQBAJ?gbpv=1&pg=PA57)

Answer (score 8):

[R' Chaim Na'eh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avraham_Chaim_Naeh) in his Shiurey Torah ([3:42](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20888&st=&pgnum=354)) calculated the weight of a Talmudic era *peruta* coin as 1/40th of a gram of silver (25mg). According to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=25%20mg%20silver%20in%20usd) this is worth 0.02 USD at the time of posting. However, this [may not be](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/5695/1535) the contemporory understanding of "*shaveh perutah*" in Halacha.

Answer (score 0):

Rav Moshe Heinemann writes in multiple places over the last couple of years (2018-2020) that he believes a peruta is about ten cents.

[Hilchos Pesach (14:4)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1798814862)

> There should be a פרוטה for every person the Rav represents. I believe
> a פרוטה is about 10 cents today. Rav Moshe writes if you can’t buy
> anything with a penny, then it’s not considered a פרוטה . Even bubble
> gum balls are more than a nickel. Therefore, if you represent 1,000
> people, you need at least $100 which the non-Jew would give to the Rav
> selling the chametz. Moreover, the Rav needs to receive another פרוטה
> for every person represented if he plans to sell the place of the
> chametz too.

[Hilchos Shidduchim through Sheva Berachos (3:10)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0851KBW2H)

> The Rambam says the value of a peruta is a חֲצִי שְּעוֹרָה של כ סף –
> half the size of a barley kernel made of pure silver. How much is that
> worth? It fluctuates daily. Most silver sold today is sterling silver
> which is .925 silver, which is not 100% silver. The reason for that is
> the same reason why we use 14 karat gold for a ring rather than pure
> 24 karat gold. Gold is a soft metal, so if you press down on the ring
> then it will get bent out of shape. Therefore, they mix the gold with
> nickel or other metal which stiffens the gold. That’s why gold rings
> are only .585 or 14 karat gold, while the rest of it is some other
> metal. Pure silver is much more expensive than just another 110 above
> sterling silver. They have to purify the silver to the point of having
> no other impurities inside. Still, this value today is worth a few
> cents. Rav Moshe Feinstein says that a peruta is the smallest coin
> which still has a value. I remember in the good old days when you
> could buy two gum chiclets with one cent or weigh yourself for a
> penny. Now it costs 25 cents to weigh yourself. At one point you could
> buy a ball of bubble gum for 5 cents, but now it costs ten cents or
> more. Of course you could buy a one cent postage stamp but you’re
> essentially trading one penny for another penny which doesn’t mean
> anything. If you’re fast enough you can also get one cent worth of
> gasoline, but there’s nothing you can do with that. I believe there is
> nothing significant that you can buy nowadays for less than ten cents.
> Therefore, a peruta would require at least ten cents. The Gemara says
> someone was mekadesh a woman with a date, so they needed to evaluate
> whether the date was worth a peruta at that time. Based on that, I
> guess you would need to investigate whether ten cents could buy
> something if someone uses it for Kiddushin.