# How much is a Prutah in cents/agurot?

Tags: halacha, money

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cash value of ‘perutah’](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5685/cash-value-of-perutah)

Various laws mention a minimum monetary amount `Prutah` or `Shaveh Prutah`.

How much is this in cents/agurot?

Also, how do we calculate this value?

Comment: Probably `Shaveh Ferutah`.

Comment: yeh a typo, i fixed that... after I submitted this question I looked at the related questions and found that it was asked