# Can a wedding band be made of multiple colors of gold?

Tags: wedding

To be kosher, a wedding band need be solid gold, so as not to leave room to question the value of the ring. As much of the gold used in jewelry is often 14k or 18k gold, as previous questions have addressed, it's acceptable to use white/rose/et c gold for the ring, but, assuming unadorned and without engraving, **is a combination of these different varieties of gold still acceptable for a kosher wedding band?**

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5685/cash-value-of-perutah

Comment: Kosher after-the-fact yes; advisable ... hm, I could see a rabbi going either way on it -- so ask the officiant. The original custom is just "no stones." On the flipside ... the reason for that is we want easily-ascertained value; here I'd assume its value is the weight of the gold, plus some additional amount for the complex design. Rabbi J David Bleich's lecture for rabbinic students advises "any design they can easily make hundreds of, given a mold" ... how is a multi-gold ring made?