# Which US half-dollar coin should be used for Zecher Machatzis Hashekel?

Tags: halacha, money, purim

It is customary on Taanis Esther to give a coin (or three coins each) valued at half the local currency's standard unit to tzedakah in commemoration of the mitzvah of Machatzis Hashekel ([Rema 694:1](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A6%D7%93#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.90)).

In America, there are [a number of different half-dollars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_dollar_%28United_States_coin%29#Designs).  Most common in circulation are silver half-dollars and copper-clad nickel half-dollars.  Ideally, should one give the silver half-dollar?

Comment: [Related](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1357/machatziz-hashekel/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Rama says](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49628&st=&pgnum=318&hilite=) "the coin that is established in that place, in that time" המטבע הקבוע באותו מקום ובאותו זמן . The current half dollar which is not silver would suffice.

[Kaf HaChaim 694:20](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9082&st=&pgnum=344&hilite=) indicates that it is preferable to use real silver.

Comment: Which is more established? They're all [legal tender for all debts public and private](http://ericpetersautos.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/cash-tender.jpg).

Comment: @Double AA: I would bet that most people use the copper-clad nickel half-dollar as a half dollar, as the silver ones by far exceeds its value.

Comment: @GershonGold fine that it would suffice - no question there - but would the silver one be a hiddur?

Comment: http://www.dailyhalacha.com/displayRead.asp?readID=1392&txtSearch=halacha