# How much is 2 Zuz worth in current USD?

Tags: passover, money, passover-seder-hagada, song-poetry, animals

As mentioned in the Passover Hagaddah, how much is "2 Zuz" worth in March 2013 US Dollars?

Please note there may be different types of Zuz: "זוזי פשיטי" and "זוזי ממש" ([Ketuvot 67a](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.67a.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).
This may be the Zuz in question: [link](http://www.acsearch.info/record.html?id=631023) .

This [Aish.com article](http://www.aish.com/atr/Ketubah_200_Zuz.html) appears to imply 2 Zuz is worth $7.50:

But that seems cheap for a little goat, even one that can be eaten by a single cat, which can be easily bitten by a dog, which was doing the right thing in defending the goat and didn't deserve to be beaten by a stick, which deserved to be burned by the fire, which... you get the idea.

So what's 2 Zuz worth? How much did this baby goat go for in USD?

Comment: Closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16261

Comment: מועדים לשמחה! The Gemara suggests that a bald goat (non-wool-producing) or a cheap ram may cost four zuzim (Shabbos 152a and Kerisus 27a, respectively). Both cases apparently refer to adult animals.

Comment: Ari, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for posting this question! Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: Also closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5685 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1357

Comment: according to here, 200 zuz is $666 in 1984 dollars: http://books.google.co.cr/books?id=VaaMVeiy-E8C&lpg=PA166&ots=OE9rVh7Il3&pg=PA166#v=onepage&q&f=false - This is based on a article by Aharon Shapiro on The Treatment of Poverty in the Torah in International Review of Economics and Ethics vol 1, No 2. -- see the link for a breakdown.

Answer (score 10):

It's virtually impossible to compare money from such a long time ago.

Common comparisons are:

- Value of precious metal.
- Cost of a days meal.
- Days labor.

Each measure will give you a different number. For a goat probably a days labor is the best measure, since that's what you would have to do to get one.

A day laborer (unskilled) in those days would earn about one *denarius* (same as a zuz) per day.

Federal minimum wage in the US for a days labor is about $58, so your goat cost about $116. Although practically speaking most people can expect more since state minimum wage is higher, and someone earning minimum wage with a family (which is comparable to the situation back then) would get a large refund on their tax return. So the real number is probably higher.

Precious metal price you already know: $7.50.

In terms of food a Zuz is worth about $20 according to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denarii). So $40 in that case.

Comment: That's not the after tax dollar. So it should be lower

Comment: @user4951 yes but the Zuz a laborer makes was also before taxes (e.g. head-tax and the like)

Answer (score 7):

Well first you need to determine what a Zuz is worth.  [Here is an article specifically talking about the 200Zuz of a Ketubah and it's various understandings, from $750-$1,000,000.](http://www.jlaw.com/Articles/KETUBAH.pdf)  Current custom in Israel is to not evaluate the actual worth of Talmudic coins but to equate it to purchasing power, technically known as relative worth.  [You can see this in action with US Dollars here](http://www.measuringworth.com/uscompare/).  According to the Rabbinate the current relative worth of 200zuz is equivalent to $50000USD [which is explained here](http://www.lawguide.co.il/articles/1119/%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%94-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%93%D7%94-%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%94-%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%99-_9295/).  Coinicidentally this past October I was maseder kiddushin in the US.  I asked Rav Ovadia Yosef before I wrote the Ketubah, if the $50k stipulation should also be included in an American Ketubah, where it wasn't mandated by state law and there were differing opinions concerning the value of a Zuz and he told me that it should still be written explicitly that 200zuz is equal to $50000USD.

So 50000/200=250.  250*2=500.  So 2zuz is $500(or possibly considerably less if you follow another valid opinion).

Comment: I think you are confusing Zuzim with Zekukim. The Gemora mandates 200 (or 100 for widow/divorcee) zuzim for a Kesuba, and there is discussion whether this is pure Zuz, or Zuz Medina. Whatever the case, as the article you linked to explains this is a very small amount of money. However, the Ashkenazi Kesuba adds a requirement to pay 200 "Zekukim", which is what may be worth $50,000, but has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: No. Starting on the bottom of page 5 and continuing onto page six of the article I cited, "The Mishnah and the Jerusalem Talmud19 indicates that the base amount of "200 zuz" is meant to correspond to a year's worth of support for a single person.20"  Which is how the Israel Rabbabut comes to the $50,000USD assesement.

Comment: Continuing on that line, Sephardi Ketubot specify Zuzim, not Zukim, the specific language of the Ketubah approved by Rav Ovadia is this, "סך הכל חמישים אלף דולר מארצות הברית בר ממאתן זוזי דחזי"  Clearly it is talking about Zuzim.

Comment: Yes, I see now what you are referring to - this is according to the opinion that nowadays we don't evaluate Talmudic coins by their weight in silver, but rather in terms of their (contemporary) purchasing power. It might be a good idea to make this clear in your answer.

Answer (score 6):

According to [R' Chaim Naeh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avraham_Chaim_Naeh) ([Shiurey Torah 3:42](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20888&st=&pgnum=354)), one Talmudic Zuz is 4.8 grams of silver (he writes that a perutah is 1/40th of a gram of silver, and that a Dinar/Zuz = 192 perutas.) WolframAlpha [calculates](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4.8%20grams%20of%20silver%20in%20usd) that to be $4.40 USD at the time of this post, or $8.80 for two Zuz.

As you mention in the question, there are two types of Zuz. The above calculation is for pure Zuz. Rashi there explains that 8 "Zuz Medina" are equal to one real Zuz, thus 2 Zuz Medina would be $1.1 USD.

However, all this is regarding the meaning of Zuz in Talmud. R' Chaim Naeh points out ([Shiurey Torah Siman 1 footnote 21](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20888&st=&pgnum=161)) that in the later Halachic works ("Poskim"), the term Zuz was used loosely for whatever coin their country happened to use. Chad Gadya is attributed to the [Rokeach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleazar_of_Worms), so it may have referring to German currency.

Comment: Does the downvoter care to explain what he finds wrong with this answer?